# Can you recognize this language? Or at least the way it declares float?

Tags: bnf

I'm working for my classes on a BNF exercise. We must explain how to declare a float and an integer based on this (imaginary?) language :

```
PROGRAM Z
    FLOAT R; I;
    FLOAT P;
    INT A;
    INT B; C; D;
    BEGIN
    R = 3;2;
    I = R + 1,5;
    A = 5;
    B = 5 * P; 
END
```

The name of this language isn't anywhere in the question (it's in French so I can't copy it in here), but I don't understand the use of ";" here.

I guess it declares R and I at the same time, and then P, but I don't understand the "R=3;2;" line. If a ";" mark a break, the program is just executing 2? Or do we attribute "3" and then "2"? Or is it just a syntax error since it's suppose to be a float and the real thing is supposed to be "3,2"?

What do you think ?

Comment: Looks like a syntax error, as `;` is already being used as the statement delimiter. Then again, it's also used to separate variable definitions, but I don't think that's an issue

Comment: I guess it is some kind of tuple. R could stand for real and I for imaginary.

Comment: Mmm yeah maybe it's a tuple but why declare it as a float then ? It doesn't make sense !

Comment: Well, hard to say. Maybe it should read `3,2`, or `3;2` is some kind of arithmetic like 3 divided by 2 or 3 to the power of 2 ....